# Do these sentences make sense?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to say “He has been working in this company since he graduated from university. We consider him as family".

他大学毕业以后，一直在这家公司工作。我们以他为家。
他大学毕业就在这家公司工作。我们以他为家。

I wasn't sure if I was using 一直，就 ＆ 以【。。。】为 correctly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since there is already an answer from @r13, I just want to point out that there is a world of difference between "为家" and "为家人" The former is treating a certain "place" as "home"; the latter is treating a certain "person" as "family"

Comment: Also, it is OK to just say "毕业后" in the context of this sentence. Good stylistic Chinese writings always aim for brevity, and redundancy is a linguistic crime worse than murder :)  And as @r13 pointed out, even the 后 may not be necessary in a certain syntactic rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自大学毕业以后，他一直都在这家公司工作，我们都視他为家人。

他自大学毕业就在这家公司工作。我们都當他是家人。

Comment: I am using the Integrated Chinese Vol 4 and the structure taught was 以____为. I was wondering if I can use 以 instead of 视 and 當 without changing the meaning?

Comment: I think the pattern of 以____为____ should be: 以 + noun + 为 + adj. 以他為榮; 以此為樂; 以生命為主. Please check your book for the pattern and examples.

Comment: The book didn't specify. It says  以 X 为 Y. Translated into "to regard or treat X as Y"

Answer (score 1):

> 以他为家

> thinking him as a home
> taking it as a home

for example,

> 这园子里有间荒废的石屋。在采摘草药的这几天，我们都以它为家。
> The garden has a desserted stone house. During the few days we tried to collect Chinese herb medicine, we relied on it to be home.

so it should be

> 他大学毕业以后，一直在这家公司工作。我们都视他为家人。
> He worked in this company since college graduation. We all view  him as family. (We all treat him like family).